# Como puedo agregar esta funcion de coffescript a mi input tag para formatear el texto

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, coffeescript

Tengo esta funcion de coffeescript que me gustaria agregar a mi textfield ya intente de muchas maneras pero no logro resolver el problema.

esta es mi funcion

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
     format = (value) -> console.log(accounting.formatMoney(value, "", 2, ".", ","))
```

Estoy usando una gema de rails "accounting.js"

este es el input a donde deseo agregarlo

```
= f.text_field(:dr_business_remuneration,  maxlength: 28, class: 'form-control only-numbers-money monto', title: t('tooltip.natural_person.dr_business_remuneration'), autocomplete: 'off', disabled:disabled_fields, )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un archivo `.js` en la siguiente ruta `/app/assets/javascripts/`, y coloca tu código.